# Idiom/phrase that means "at the slightest annoyance"

Tags: word-request, idioms

I'm looking for an idiom or phrase that means "at the slightest bit of annoyance". I want to use it in the following context:

> "Jesus!" It was a word my boss would spit out **at the drop of a hat**.

I wanted to avoid "at the slightest provocation" because that could imply that the speaker provoked his/her boss, which is not what I'm trying to say. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's wrong with *at the slightest annoyance*?

Comment: And what's wrong with "*at the drop of a hat*"?

Comment: @cornbreadninja I'm looking for a set idiom/phrase (if there is one) to give the sentence more color/impact.

Comment: @Daniel Because I was told that with "a drop of a hat" the "instant, unplanned activity" connotation is stronger than the "at the slightest provocation" one. Looking at the dictionary definitions and sentences online, I have to agree that is possible. So I'm looking for a better alternative.

Comment: @Soulz I don't think that's really true. They both have very strong connotations of "instant, unplanned activity." Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Daniel No, the sentence is focusing more on the irritability of the boss. I think there is a slight difference. I'm not sure I'm explaining myself properly though. :(

Comment: @Soulz If that's not what you're looking for, I don't think anybody will be able to help you becaues both of those phrases strongly indicate that the boss is an irritable, on-edge type of guy. You will need to give a better explanation of what you are looking for.

Comment: @Soulz "At the drop of a hat" in the context that you gave above would definitely be understood to mean "at the slightest provocation"

Comment: I think this is POB. OP already has common expressions covering both formal/literal *(at the slightest provocation)* and informal/idiomatic *(at the drop of a hat)* contexts, so I can't see any point in asking ELL to throw up more alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

We seemed to be getting about as far as we can in comments alone, so I've summarized them here. Any other options anyone can think of can be added below.

The examples listed below convey a boss who is short-tempered and likely to overreact to any minor issues which come up during the day. All the examples you listed in your original question get that meaning across, and none imply that the speaker provoked the boss character -- at least not from the perspective of any reasonable person (the boss may think the worker provoked him).

> ...at the slightest annoyance.
>
> ...at the drop of a hat.
>
> ...at the slightest provocation.
>
> ...without warning.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider changing the preposition *at*, and using something that suggests more spontaneity. For example, you could try:

> ...is a word my boss would spit out...
>
> - whenever he was flustered.
> - the moment he got upset.
> - as soon as the pressure got to him.

That said, I agree with cornbread; I don't think there's anything wrong with:

> - at the slightest annoyance.

That seems to work just fine, too.